# Minesweeper in C

Tags: c, time

The game works perfectly, but I want to add a timer that measures and shows at the end of the game, the time the player's game lasted.

The code is a classic game of minesweeper where the user gives the coordinates of the point he wants to discover from the board, the game is made in c, not in C#.

The game consists of clearing all the squares of a two-dimensional arrangement that do not hide a mine. Some squares will have a random mine while others will not. The user is asked to position a box in the two-dimensional arrangement, if he does not find a mine he will continue the game until he wins, otherwise he will finish the game and the user will lose.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FLUSH fflush(stdin)

void difficulty( void );
void beginner( void );
void intermediate( void );
void expert( void );
void minefield_generator( void );
void print_minefield( void );
void guess( void );
void boom( void );
void print_final_minefield( void );
void win( void );
void play_again( void );
void game_over( void );

int x, y;
int M, N;
float diff;
int total_mines = 0;
int mines = 0;
int minefield[30][30];                                      //This 2-D array contains all of the mines, numbers and blank spaces
int blank_minefield[30][30];                                //This contains the minefield full of '|-|' characters
int final_minefield[30][30];

int main()
{
    printf("\t\tWelcome to Minesweeper\n");
    difficulty();
    return 0;
}

void difficulty( void )                                     //Function for choosing the difficulty level
{
    diff = 0;
    while( (diff != 1) && (diff != 2) && (diff != 3) && (diff != 4))        
    {
        printf("\t\tChoose a difficulty level(1-3) or 4 for a custom game:");   
        scanf("%f", &diff);
        FLUSH;
        if( (diff != 1) && (diff != 2) && (diff != 3) && (diff != 4))
        {
            printf("\t\tPlease enter either 1, 2, 3 or 4\n");
        }
    }   

    if( diff == 1 )                                         //If, else if and else statements that each go to the respective difficulty
    {
        beginner();
    }
    else if( diff == 2 )
    {
        intermediate();
    }
    else if( diff == 3 )
    {
        expert();
    }
    else if( diff == 4)
    {
        custom();
    }
}

void beginner( void )                                       //Gives the minefield the 'beginner' grid and mines
{
    M = 9;
    N = 9;
    total_mines = 10;
    minefield_generator();
    guess();
}

void intermediate( void )                                   //Gives the minefield the 'intermediate' grid and mines
{
    M = 16;
    N = 16;
    total_mines = 40;
    minefield_generator();
    guess();
}

void expert( void )                                         //Gives the minefield the 'expert' grid size and mines
{
    M = 16;
    N = 30;
    total_mines = 99;
    minefield_generator();
    guess();
}

void custom( void )
{
    M = 0;
    N = 0;
    total_mines = 0;
    printf("\t\tPlease enter the size of the dimensions you want\n");
    printf("\t\tFirst value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("\t\tSecond value:\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("\t\tNumber of mines you want to assign to the board:\n");
    scanf("%d", &total_mines);
    minefield_generator();
    guess();
}

void minefield_generator( void )                            //Function that generates the minefield
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    srand( time( NULL ) );                                  //Starts the random no. generator

    while( j < N )                                          //Nested loop for making the blank minefield and final minefield
    {
        while( i < M)
        {
            minefield[i][j] = '-';
            blank_minefield[i][j] = minefield[i][j];        
            final_minefield[i][j] = minefield[i][j];        
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
    mines = 0;
    while( mines < total_mines )                            //Randomly generates the mines into the minefield
    {
        i = rand()%(M);
        j = rand()%(N);
        if( minefield[i][j] != '*')                         //If statement that checks if there is a mine already there and doesn't place a mine if there is
        {
            minefield[i][j] = '*';
            final_minefield[i][j] = minefield[i][j];
            mines++;
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while( j < N )                                          //While loop that generates the numbers for any adjacent mines
    {
        while( i < M)
        {
            if( minefield[i][j] != '*')
            {
                minefield[i][j] = 0;
            }   
            if((minefield[i-1][j-1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i-1][j] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i][j-1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i-1][j+1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i+1][j-1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i+1][j] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i][j+1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            if((minefield[i+1][j+1] == '*') && (minefield[i][j] != '*'))
            {
                minefield[i][j]++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
}

void print_minefield(void)                                  // This function prints the minefield
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0;
    while( z < M )                                          // This while loop prints out the line of co-ordinates along the x axis of the minefield
    {
        if( z == 0 )
        {
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("|%d|\t", z);
        z++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    while( j < N )                                          // Loop that prints out each character in the minefield                         
    {   
        printf("|%d|\t", j);
        while( i < M)
        {
            if( blank_minefield[i][j] == '-')
            {
                printf("|%c|\t", blank_minefield[i][j]);

            }
            else if( minefield[i][j] == 0 )                 // This changes any spaces with values of zero to the character 'B'
            {
                blank_minefield[i][j] = 'B';                
                printf("|%c|\t", blank_minefield[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("|%d|\t", blank_minefield[i][j]);

            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
}


void guess( void )
{
    int q = 0, i=0, j=0, match=0;
    print_minefield();
    while( j < N )                                          // While loop for testing whether or not the user has cleared the minefield
    {
        while( i < M )
        {
            if(minefield[i][j] == blank_minefield[i][j])
            {
                match++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
    if( match == (( M * N ) - total_mines))                 // If the user has cleared the minefield, the win() function is run
    {
        win();
    }
    printf("\nEnter the x value, then a space, then the y value:");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);                                 // Reading in the co-ordinates for the guess
    FLUSH;
    if( (x >= M) || (x < 0) || (y < 0) || (y >= N) )
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a value inside the grid\n");
        guess();
    }
    if( minefield[x][y] == '*' )                            // Runs the boom() function if the user selects a mine
    {
        boom();
    }
    if( blank_minefield[x][y] != '-' )
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter a value that has not already been entered\n");
        guess();
    }

    else                                                // Checks if the adjacent spaces are blank, then changes the values in the blank_minefield array. Because they are changed, they will now print out in the print_minefield function
    {
        blank_minefield[x][y] = minefield[x][y];
        if( minefield[x][y] == 0 )
        {
            if( minefield[x-1][y-1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x-1][y] = minefield[x-1][y];
            }
            if( minefield[x-1][y] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x-1][y] = minefield[x-1][y];
            }
            if( minefield[x][y-1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x][y-1] = minefield[x][y-1];
            }
            if( minefield[x-1][y+1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x-1][y+1] = minefield[x-1][y+1];
            }
            if( minefield[x+1][y-1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x+1][y-1] = minefield[x+1][y-1];
            }
            if( minefield[x+1][y] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x+1][y] = minefield[x+1][y];
            }
            if( minefield[x][y+1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x][y+1] = minefield[x][y+1];
            }
            if( minefield[x+1][y+1] == 0 )
            {
                blank_minefield[x+1][y+1] = minefield[x+1][y+1];
            }
        }
        guess();
    }
}

void boom( void )                                       // Runs the print_final_minefield function, then the play_again function                    
{
    print_final_minefield();
    printf("\n\t\tYou hit a mine at %d,%d\n\t\tYOU LOSE!!!!", x, y);
    play_again();
}

void print_final_minefield( void )                      // Prints the minefield, showing where all of the mines are placed
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0;
    while( z < M )
    {
        if( z == 0 )
        {
            printf("\t");
        }
        printf("|%d|\t", z);
        z++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    while( j < N )
    {   
        printf("|%d|\t", j);
        while( i < M)
        {
            printf("|%c|\t", final_minefield[i][j]);
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i = 0;
        j++;
    }
}

void win( void )                                        // Runs the play_again function
{
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tYOU WIN!!!!!\n\n\n");
    play_again();
}

void play_again( void )                                 // Gives the user the option to play again
{
    char option[2];
    printf("\n\t\tWould you like to play again(Y/N)?:");
    scanf("%c", &option[0]);
    FLUSH;
    if((option[0] == 'Y') || (option[0] == 'y'))        // Restarts the program from after the welcome message
    {
        difficulty();
    }
    else if( (option[0] == 'N') || (option[0] == 'n'))
    {
        game_over();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter either Y or N");
        play_again();
    }
}

void game_over( void )                                  // Ends the program
{
    printf("\n\n\t\tGame Over");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You have to show some of your code. Otherwise, we won't be really able to help you. Sorry for welcoming you like this on this site, but that's how StackOverflow works !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RyoShiina  I'm sorry, it's the first post I've done and I couldn't put the code in.

Comment: @DeiDei I'm sorry, it's the first post I've done and I couldn't put the code in.

Comment: @JoseLuisMendoza it's okay don't worry, we all learn that way !

Comment: Try `time` (to get the time) and `difftime` (to compute the difference between two times).

Comment: @user3386109 I don't know how or where to implement it

Comment: Read the time when the game starts. Then, before every call to `scanf`, read the time again and compute the difference. Show the difference on-screen in the `print_minefield` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function clock() to catch the moment’s clock, and then use the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC to calculate how many second has gone by. Like this:

```
int timeInSeconds;
clock_t start = clock(), end,total;

 ...

end = clock();
total = end - start;
timeInSeconds = total/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: What makes clock() better than time() ? Btw: time is already included and used

Comment: How can I implement it in this code?

Comment: `clock` is not the answer. `clock` returns the amount of [processor time used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time), which is not the same as [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time).